# Jquery fadeIn function on Div is not working with FF and IE but it does work with anoter Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a `linkbutton` which `onclick` has to `FadeIn` a div and it does work.On google chrome it works but on FF and IE doesnt.The strange thing is that i have another linkbutton which FadesIn another div with all browsers.

Link to the problem i descripe >  [hotelmontecristobg.com](http://hotelmontecristobg.com/)

press english button Accomodation hover and press StandartRoom when using Chrome it works and FadesIn but on FF and IE it doesnt.

Here is the code
working div for all browsers:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Inquiry" class="inquiry">
    <img id="closeY" class="close" src="Logos/closeY.png" />

    <table style="width:60%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="l1" style="font-size:30px;"> Запитване </asp:Label>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="l2" runat="server" style="font-size:22px;width:100px;">Вашият Имейл</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" style="font-size:22px;width:300px;"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="color:red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="l3" runat="server" style="font-size:22px;width:100px;">Тема</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="t2" style="font-size:22px;width:300px;"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="color:red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="l4" runat="server" style="font-size:22px;width:100px;">Текст</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea runat="server" id="TextArea" style="height:200px;width:300px;max-height:200px;max-width:300px;"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="color:red"></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="l5" style="font-size:22px;width:100px;">Телефон:</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="telephone" runat="server" style="font-size:22px;width:300px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button id="izprati" runat="server" style="width:300px;height:50px" OnClick="izprati_Click" Text="Изпрати" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>



<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Hbutton2" CssClass="HButton">
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hbutton2').click(function() {
        $('#Inquiry').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#closeY', function() {
        $('#Inquiry').fadeOut(1000);
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.inquiry {
    position: fixed !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10vw;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px black;
}
```

And the Div that FadesIn with Google Chrome and not with FireFox and InternetExplorer.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#StayOpen1').click(function() {
    $("#situationalpanel").fadeOut(1000);
    $('#DeluxeR').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#OneBedR').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#standartR').fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AccomodationPanel">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen1" CssClass="StayOpen"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

**CSS of #standartR:**

```
.standart {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 80vw;
    left: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    top: 10vh;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#292929, #999999);
 /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#292929, #999999);
 /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#292929, #999999);
 /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#292929, #999999);
 /* Standard syntax */;
}
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html as well? is inqiury an Id or a class?

Comment: Edditted to see the Inquery HTML

Comment: so If I am not wrong, the inquiry part works fine and the stayopen part is not working?

Comment: exactly inquiry works for all browsers and stayopen works fine on chrome and doesnt FadesIn on click with FF and IE

Comment: ok. can you share the html required for the stayOpen button click? i dont see the situationpanel and other div's in your html